# Tag Health: A question quality widget

Tags: script

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​[image: Tag Health is a sidebar widget that monitors the question quality of a given set of tags on a Stack Exchange site with a sample of about 500 most recent questions.]
[image: Question quality. Visualized. lt plots the question score against reputation of the asker and gives you a graphical representation of the recent performance of the tag. Jump right in. With everyhing plotted, it is very easy to locate different questions based on score and reputation. Once you have identified a point, just click on it and you can dive right into the question. More perspectives. It comes with a set of filters that let you customize the graph with additional parameters. Whether you want to get an overview or focus on a specific portion of the questions, Tag Health has the right tools for you.]
[image: Get ready. To use Tag Health, install the userscript and go to the tagged questions page. You can get there by clicking on any tags or visit the /questions/tagged/<tag name> page of any Stack Exchange sites. The widget is located on the sidebar below the tag summary.]
[image][image: Install userscript][image][image: View source]

Comment: I know the infographic looks great and all, but... could we have some text too?

Comment: @michaelb958 Like `alt` text, `title` text or actual text? I wish I could use actual text, but it is hard to create layouts with Markdown. At least I've got the excerpt.

Comment: Trying to read this post on the Android app is almost impossible. There is no way to zoom the image. Add some plain text, please.

Comment: @atticae I can read this on the iOS app pretty easily. [Tapping on the image allows me to zoom in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzHDN.png) If that functionality doesn't exist in the Android app, you should post a feature request on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com). Plus, this script can only be used on a computer only.